# Scoping of socket.io server side and client side objects in express routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In my app.js I have

```
var app = express();
var serv = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serv);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   //some code here
}

var SessionSockets = require('session.socket.io'),
    sessionSockets = new SessionSockets(io, express_store, cookieParser);
sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
   //set up some socket handlers here for the specific client  that are 
   //only called when a client does a socket.emit. 
   //These handlers have access to io, sessionSockets, socket, session objects.
}
```

How can the express routes access a particular client's socket reference after processing a post/get which is not triggered by a client `socket.emit` but triggered by a client post/get. What is the best way to scope the `socket.io server(io/sessionSockets)/client(socket)` objects in routes so that I can get **this** client's socket reference easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These three steps helped me to the solve the problem. This identifies tabs also uniquely as that was one of my requirements.

1. On connection, join using `socket.id` and then send the `socket.id` back to the client using

   ```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socket.join(socket.id);   
     socket.emit('server_socket_id', {socket_id : socket.id});
   }
   ```
2. Client receives the emit event using

   ```
   socket.on('server_socket_id', function(data){
     //assign some global here which can be sent back to the server whenever required.
     server_socket_id = data.socket_id;
   });
   ```
3. In `app.js` I fetch the corresponding socket like this and pass it on to the routes.

   ```
   app.post('/update', function(req, res){
     var socket_id = req.body.socket_id;
     route.update(req, res, io.sockets.in(socket_id).sockets[socket_id]);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `socket.io` authorization setting, although the module `session.socket.io` was created specifically for that purpose. Each time a socket establishes a connection, there is handshake data that is stored (although I've heard that flashsockets won't pass the browser cookies). This is what it looks like (and is similarly written in the module you're using):

```
io.configure(function () {
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    //error object, then boolean that allows/denies the auth
    callback(null, true);
  });
});
```

What you could do from here is parse the cookie, then store a reference to that socket by the cookie name. So you would add this to the authorization setting:

```
var data = handshakeData;
if (data.headers.cookie) {
  //note that this is done differently if using signed cookies
  data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
  data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
}
```

Then, when you listen on connections, store the client by session identifier:

```
var clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //store the reference based on session ID
  clients[socket.handshake.sessionID] = socket;
});
```

And when you receive an HTTP request in Express, you can fetch it like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //I've currently forgotten how to get session ID from request,
  //will go find after returning from school
  var socket = clients[sessionID];
});
```

Comment: This requires manual maintenance of clients hashmap. More details are mentioned here http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/#comment-1158

Comment: What's wrong with manually managing the clients? Would you rather iterate the client list and match cookies individually?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Creating a session specific namespace with `socket.join(socket.handshake.sessionID)` would maintain the hashmap automatically when the client opens/closes  the browser. But then I want to identify multiple tabs in a unique way. Session ID is not unique across tabs.